# Finding duplicates in array of arrays and processing them

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having Data in array of arrays with duplicate arrays of Oth position.
  **explanation**
Compare arrays with its zero th position and make the result accurately.

```
let array = [["2018-03-09", 10, 11, 0],["2018-03-10", 100, 101, 105],["2018-03-15", 20, 0, 25],["2018-03-09", 0, 0, 15],["2018-03-15", 0, 10, 0]]
let output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let key = array[i][0]
  let index = output.findIndex(x => x[0] == key)
  if (index >= 0) {
    for (let k = 1; k < array[i].length; k++) {
      if (array[i][k] >= output[index][i]) {

        output[index][k] = array[i][k]
      } else {
        output[index][k] = output[index][i]
      }

    }
  } else {
    output.push(array[i])
  }
}
console.log(output)
```

Required Output

```
output=[["2018-03-09",10,11,15],["2018-03-10",100,101,105],["2018-03-15",20,10,25]]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please indent your code, it is very hard to read.

Comment: You should have let the previous array indentation in place. Now we have an unhandy horizontal scrollbar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lookup object to find previous entries with the same values, then merge them. Array destructuring is helpful to make the code clean:

```
 const byDate = {};
 const result = [];

 for(const [date, ...values] of array) {
  if(byDate[date]) {
    values.forEach((v, i) => byDate[date][i + 1] = Math.max(byDate[date][i + 1], v));
  } else {
    result.push(byDate[date] = [date, ...values]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: @amesshil well `15 + 0` will result in the same thing as `Math.max(15, 0)`, hard to tell which behaviour is wanted.

Comment: @amesshil but you are right, from the code it is clear what the OP wanted, edited accordingly. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: @JonasWilms can you provide solution for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991800/convert-array-of-objects-to-array-of-arrays-in-specified-format

Answer (score 0):

For better readability, you can update the array in a separate function (I kept the `for` loop method you used, although we could use here a `forEach()` call).

Here, updateEntry will look in an output array (`entries` argument) for an existing `entry`, updating it if found otherwise it will append it to the output array.

Below a working snippet.

```js
function updateEntry(entries, entry) {
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    if (entry[0] != entries[i][0]) continue;
    for (let j = 1; j < entry.length; j++) {
      if (entry[j] >= entries[i][j])
        entries[i][j] = entry[j];
    }
    return;
  }
  entries.push(entry);
}

let array = [
  ["2018-03-09", 10, 11, 0],
  ["2018-03-10", 100, 101, 105],
  ["2018-03-15", 20, 0, 25],
  ["2018-03-09", 0, 0, 15],
  ["2018-03-15", 0, 10, 0]
];
let output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  updateEntry(output, array[i]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.reduce to build an object with the identifier (the date) as the keys, which sums the other three values.  Then, use Object.values to return your desired array output.

```js
let array = [["2018-03-09", 10, 11, 0],["2018-03-10", 100, 101, 105],["2018-03-15", 20, 0, 25],["2018-03-09", 0, 0, 15],["2018-03-15", 0, 10, 0]];

let output = Object.values(array.reduce((r, e) => {
  var k = e[0];
  
  if (!r[k]) r[k] = [k, 0, 0, 0];

  r[k][1] += e[1];
  r[k][2] += e[2];
  r[k][3] += e[3];
 
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```